# how to enlarge all contents on my website when it is viewed on a larger computer?

Tags: html, css, view, dreamweaver

I am making a single page website and want to achieve similar results as this kenzo website:

http://www.kenzo.com

It is amazing how the boxes at the center is smaller on small screen computer but much larger on large screen computer. How do you do that?

I was thinking "positioning" in CSS style may do the trick, so I tried setting the left:0% and right:0%. But I found that it only makes the image center at the middle, not making it enlarge on large screen computers.

Anyone has any idea to solve this?

Comment: @Sowmya — To quote the question: "I was thinking "positioning" in CSS style may do the trick, so I tried setting the left:0% and right:0%. But I found that it only makes the image center at the middle, not making it enlarge on large screen computers."

Comment: You should read up on [responsive web design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) There is no single css trick that will ensure consistent results. If you just want it for the image, you probably need `width:100%`

Comment: You linked to a flash website. That effect has not been done with css.

Comment: As said: look into responsive webdesign and media queries. Be warned, though, that older browsers don't support media queries. JQuery should be quite a help in such cases (add class to body and style elements in css accordingly).

Answer (score 1):

Anyways here is the sample. Check it. Re-size the result section in demo to see the effect

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
<header></header>
<div class="content"><img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-yAOYE3-J1mo/TmsnBJ6ucYI/AAAAAAAABcA/5ZKqEv3p-6I/s1600/36676-sky_blue.jpg" /></div>
<footer>footer</footer>
</div>​
```

CSS

```
body{margin:0; padding:0}
.wrapper{width:100%;}
header{height:60px; background:green}
.content{position:relative; padding:30px; background:grey; }
.content img{max-width:100%}
footer{height:40px; background:red; }​
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7Hrme/)

Answer (score 1):

I've checked kenzo.com's code: They use JavaScript (and jQuery) to get that effect. Something like:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    $('.content').css('width', $(this).width()/2);
});
```

But this is not necessary and I even would consider it bad practice.

You sould rather use `media queries` to have different css-Styles for different viewport or screen resolutions.
Check out this very useful articles:

[MSN: CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries)

[Smashing Magazine: How To Use CSS3 Media Queries...](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/)